# Is there a way to replace variable characters in variable length within similar symbol such as ( )?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

The items in one column  `name`

```
Tritton AX 180: Universal Gaming Headset (PS3/Xbox 360/PC/Mac)
Rome: Total War - White Label (PC DVD)
Railworks3 - Train Simulator 2012 (PC)
```

I would like to get :

```
Tritton AX 180: Universal Gaming Headset
Rome: Total War - White Label
Railworks3 - Train Simulator 2012
```

I have looked into `replace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100) = 
       'Tritton AX 180: Universal Gaming Headset (PS3/Xbox 360/PC/Mac)'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, 0, CHARINDEX('(',@s))
```

So if your column name is `name` then

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 0, CHARINDEX('(',name) )
```